# What to do about link-only questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, link-only-answers

There's been much discussion about link-only answers, but there seems to be an increasing trend towards link-only questions. These are usually of the form *'My code is here (insert link) - please fix'* or *'This (insert link) is my web site. Why isn't it working'*. (Examples of the latter [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27651790/1864610) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27652250/1864610) I'm sure there are many more.

In both cases I have down-voted, voted to close and left a comment, but both are still open after some hours. One has even been upvoted. Apart from leaving a more strongly worded comment explaining whay this is a problem here there is little more I can do.

Is there anything that can be implemented in the quality filters that will help reduce the incidence of such lazy questions?